# Why I can't go anywhere on my horse?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Sometimes, when I get on my horse and ride somewhere, a few seconds later the game returns me to where I started. How can I fix this?

Comment: Most common cause of this is going to be lag if you are on a server or the like. Single player, no idea. I am not sure we can answer this but you will need to be more specific with some details if we are going to have a chance of helping.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me like common server lag. If you are on a server, either wait it out, or ask an Admin for help. If you are not on a server, try the following:

- Tame a new horse
- Re-start your game
- Try it in another version, or if you have mods installed, without mods.
- Create a new world and try it there

If none of the above work: copy and paste your `saves` folder onto your desktop, re-download minecraft, and return your saves folder to the file. This will account for any problems in the code of the application. If you don't know how to access your `saves` folder on your device, leave a comment,.